# How to write portable Git library scripts?

Tags: git, portability

I create custom Git commands by writing scripts in `/usr/local/libexec/git` and creating aliases to invoke them. For example:

```
git config --global alias.graph '!/usr/local/libexec/git/git-graph'
```

The tricky part is that I want my scripts to be "portable" in the sense that anyone who has installed Git should be able to install and run my scripts the same way I do, without encountering missing dependencies.

***Important Edit:** Following @Schwern's response, I realize I must add a bit more information. Replace "anyone who has installed Git" with "anyone who interacts with Git through the `git-core` scripts provided by the official Git sources". For example, invoking `git rebase` executes [`.../git-core/git-rebase.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-rebase.sh). (You can click that last word; it's a hyperlink, but it doesn't appear that way in all browsers.) I assume this is the situation for most Git users, as this is the default provided by the Git project itself.*

From my years of experience writing [portable shell scripts](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Portable-Shell.html), I know it's futile to expect a shell script of even moderate complexity to run on every Unix-like OS that ever existed. However, I think it's reasonable to expect a common base of utilities to exist between Git workstations, at least enough to avoid constantly jumping through hoops and walking on eggshells when writing scripts to run on these workstations.

Here are my assumptions about the Git workstations:

- All scripts in the `git-core` directory (e.g. `/usr/libexec/git-core`) have not been altered since being placed there by the Git installation.
- All scripts in `git-core` run as expected (i.e. same as on the Git maintainers' workstations, or anyone with a "normal" setup).
- The installed version of Git meets some arbitrary minimum requirement that I have decided to support with my scripts. ***Edit:** By "arbitrary", I really meant "convenient". @Schwern stated with precision what I was really trying to say here.*

How can I determine the common base of utilities I can use to write portable scripts on these Git workstations?

***Edit:** I am basically looking for a list of dependencies for the `git-core` scripts provided in the main Git distribution. This will give the common base I am looking for.*

Comment: This has nothing to do with git, and your link is a very nice writeup on what's been found to work everywhere.  Is there something unsatisfactory about the information there that drove you here?

Comment: @jthill The problem is more about writing portable scripts than about Git, but it definitely relates to Git, quite strongly in fact. Basically, I'm looking for a common set of utilities (including shell builtins) that can be expected to be found on any computer with Git installed, considering the assumptions I made. As seen by the contents of `git-core`, Git relies on this being true, as well as there being specific versions of Python and Perl installed. The advice given in the GNU manual I linked is not followed by `git-core`.

Comment: BTW while `git-p4` is Python, all other core scripts are not-Python, they're in the various "contrib" directories. I presume this is mainly to avoid depending on Python2 vs Python3 and/or all the complexity of Python library curation.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, all of Git's built in scripts (there are many, mostly `sh` and a few `perl`) live in that `git-core` directory.  Running `git xxx` attempts to execute program `git-xxx`, typically out of the `git-core` directory, after setting up various environment variables.  For instance, `git --git-dir=/path/to/some/dir` exports a `GIT_DIR=/path/to/some/dir` setting.

The precise *location* of the `git-core` directory itself is set when you build Git.  You can view it by running:

```
git --exec-path
```

Note that while `git foo` will try to run `$(git --exec-path)/git-foo`, if there is no `git-foo` in there *and* you put `git-foo` in your *own* scripting directory (that is somewhere on your `$PATH`), `git foo` will end up running *that*.  The mechanism is straightforward: the `git` front end inserts the git-core path into the front of `$PATH`:

```
$ cat << 'end' > $HOME/scripts/git-statusy
? #! /bin/sh
? echo statusy: \$PATH is $PATH
? git status
? 'end'
$ chmod +x $HOME/scripts/git-statusy
$ git statusy
statusy: $PATH is /usr/local/libexec/git-core:[...snipped]
On branch master
... [snipped]
```

Within the `git-core` directory, there is a file named `git-sh-setup` (q.v.).  This contains some convenience functions and some workarounds for known issues on systems for which Git is built.  A "core" Git script should therefore always begin with `. git-sh-setup`.  (This works because `$PATH` has the git-core directory at the front.)  Some "non-core" contrib scripts explicitly run `. $(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup` instead though.

Within your script, you can depend on any POSIX shell built-ins, except that you need to work around certain bugs (e.g., FreeBSD /bin/sh mishandles `return` in some versions).  Support for additional commands is basically on an "as found by testing" basis, as far as I know: if you look at the history of [`git-sh-setup.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-sh-setup.sh) and other `.sh` files in the Git source, you will see various changes made over time to deal with such things.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a "Git workstation" anymore than there's an "SVN workstation" or even a "Ruby workstation". It's just some machine that has Git installed and is being used to work on or obtain some project that uses Git. If they're in a Windows environment, it will be Windows. If they're on an outdated Solaris machine, it will be a Solaris environment. Since Git now comes standard with OS X, every OS X machine is a "Git workstation".

Because "Git workstation" includes Windows, and Windows doesn't come with any of the normal shell utilities, you can't use shell at all. At best you can rely on the minimal set that comes with Git Bash, but there are plenty of Windows/Git installations that don't use Git Bash. Instead, a lot of IDEs come with Git bundled in them.

None of this changes the compatibility challenges of writing portable shell scripts. BSD vs Gnu vs some commercial monstrosity, and all with the problem of what about Windows, that will all still be there.

None of this changes being polite about installing 3rd party extensions. They don't go into `/usr`, that's for system stuff and should remain unmodified. They go in something like `/usr/local` or even `~/bin`. Git scripts will work if they are in the user's `PATH`.

---

As to some of your assumptions about Git...

> *All scripts in the git-core directory (e.g. /usr/libexec/git-core) have not been altered since being placed there by the Git installation.*

That's a fair assumption... if it exists. Here on OS X there is no `/usr/libexec/git-core` and I can't find any equivalent. I suspect they're all compiled into the binary. ***You can't assume Git is a pile of scripts*** or even has compatibility hard links like MacPorts does.

> *All scripts in git-core run as expected (i.e. same as on the Git maintainers' workstations, or anyone with a "normal" setup).*

Again, that's a fine assumption ***if they exist*** which they don't have to.

> *The installed version of Git meets some arbitrary minimum requirement that I have decided to support with my scripts.*

Rather than being arbitrary, pick the minimum version that supports the features your scripts need and that isn't too inconvenient for you. Always check it with `git --version`.

---

With all that in mind, to be portable...

- Use `git` directly, not via scripts.
- ***Don't*** assume "git" is anything but a binary called `git`.
- Have the installer ask for the location of the user's git binary.
- ***Don't*** dump your own extensions into /usr/libexec, put them somewhere in the user's PATH.
- ***Don't*** hard code any of the paths to where your extensions will be installed.
- ***Don't*** write anything in shell or using Unix utilities.
- Use a compiled language and provide binaries, or a commonly used scripting language like Perl or Python or Ruby and provide binary bundles.

Comment: By "Git workstation", I really meant a computer with Git installed, and all the necessary bits to have it function properly. I actually didn't know that a Unix shell was not necessary to run Git, considering that the official Git source repository itself contains a bunch of shell scripts that implement the commands. I suppose they must be offered on a "take it or leave it" basis... Hope you don't mind, but I'm going to edit my question a little bit. I appreciate your insight.

Comment: The actual location of the scripts varies on MacOS in part because XCode installs its own (Apple-modified) Git and in part because there are so many other versions. I'm using a `brew` one these days and I get: `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.2.0/libexec/git-core` ... ow, that's way out of date, I need to update :-)

Comment: @Sam Your edit doesn't change my answer. The short answer is you can't rely on anything that Git ships with it as a dependency because ***Git does not guarantee these dependencies will be there***. They're an internal, undocumented feature that can change at any time. Not only might it not exist in a different distribution, but they might go away in the next version. Git itself has been slowly migrating away from shell scripts due to portability problems. Git itself lists its dependencies in INSTALL and has `git-sh-setup.sh` to deal with incompatibilities.